# What are the general expression for the general solutions satisfying the boundary conditions $u_x(0, t)$ = 0 = $u_x(L, t)$, for all t > 0.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, wave-equation

So I have this question here, and I'm given that

$u_{xx}$ $-$ $\frac {1}{v^2}$$u_{tt}$ = $0$, where 0 < x < L, v is a constant, and
where the subscripts indicate differentiation.

So what I've done is say that $u(x,t)$ = $X(x)$$Y(t)$

but I am really unsure what to do from here. Any hints would be great. Thanks

So carrying on from here what I think is that $\frac {1}{X(x)}$$X(x)_{xx}$ = $\frac {1}{Y}$$\frac {1}{v^2}$$Y(t)_{tt}$

So setting $\frac {1}{X(x)}$$X(x)_{xx}$ = $-a^2$ where a is a constant and doing the same for $Y(t)$

Comment: First steps: Derive the equations for $X$ and $Y$ (left hand depends only on $x$ and right hand only on $t$ so it must be a constant $C$, i.e. $X''/X = C$ and $Y''/Y = v^2 C$). Solve these two ODEs with the boundary condition $X'(0) = X'(L) = 0$ to determine the allowed values of $C$. Then the general solution will be a linear combination of the solutions you have found over all the allowed values of $C$.

Comment: @Winther Ok, thanks, that's what my thinking was anyway. Cheers

Comment: @Winther Hey man I took $-a^2$ to be my constant and ended up with the result of $\sum $ $A_n$$cos((2*n*pi*x)lL)cosh((2n*pi*v*t)/L)$ and was just wondering if that was right. Thanks

Comment: Note that $a = \frac{\pi}{L}$ and $a = \frac{3\pi}{L}$ and all $a$ on the form $\pi n/L$ also works. How you got $\cosh$ for $Y$? The ODE for $Y$ and $X$ are practically the same (apart from a constant and the boundary conditions) so you should have the same type of solutions for $Y$ (and there should be two terms for $Y$).

Comment: @Winther I'm really struggling with this, and don't really understand what you mean

Comment: I'm saying that you did not solve the $Y$-equation correctly $Y''/Y = -a^2v^2$ does not have $\cosh(avt)$ as the solution, but $A\cos(avt) + B\sin(avt)$. And you seem to have found $a = 2\pi n / L$ with $n$ integer as the allowed $a$ values where it should be $a = \pi n / L$. If you correct these things then you are done.

Comment: I've got that $Y''/Y$ = $-a^2v^2$ yeah. But I dont know how to get to the full solution for $u$. I have $X(x)$ = $Acos((2*n*pi*x)/L)$ and I have $Y(t)$ = $Ccos((2*pi*n*v*t)/L) + Dsin((2*pi*n*v*t)/L)$ but I don't know where to go from there, I don't have enough boundary conditions. I need to general expression for $u$

Comment: That is as far as you can go with the information provided. To determine the constants $C_n$ and $D_n$ you need initial conditions like $u(x,0)$ and $u_t(x,0)$. What you can do is to derive a general formula for $C_n$ and $D_n$ in terms of $u(x,0)$ and $u_t(x,0)$ in terms of integrals.

Comment: @Winther Ok, thank you for your help. hopefully this helps me with my exam tomorrow